# Increasing HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm having problems with my work - I want to automatically insert a table when user registers. I've already finished the registration part but how can I show another user the users registered with table tag?

Comment: Use jQuery Ajax to append new `<tr>` row into table tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- If you are using form submit and redirection than put the table in a `foreach()` loop with the data array coming from database table. Then when ever user comes on this page it takes all the newly added values and render the table.
- Use jQuery Ajax to save the data and append new `<tr>` row into table body.